# express delete route not found

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying this code to delete specific record in mongo by id

where in angular I'm passing the Id  from the controller 
It gives error code saying 404 not found
code in Node server side file is :

```
app.delete('/contactlist/id', function (req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
console.log("in delete"+ id);
db.contactlist.remove({id : mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function ( err , doc){
    res.json(doc);
  });
});
```

and code in controller of angular :

```
    $scope.remove = function (id){
    console.log(id);
    $http.delete('/contactlist'+ id ).success( function(response) {
        refresh();
    });
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code at `$http.delete('/contactlist'+ id )` - it's supposed to reflect the actual end-point and you missed the forward slash `$http.delete('/contactlist/'+ id )`

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks ok, except

```
$http.delete('/contactlist'+ id ) //you forgot additional slash, '/contactlist/'+ id
.success( function(response) {
    refresh();
});
```

And

```
app.delete('/contactlist/id', function (req, res) { //this must be a param '/contactlist/:id'
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log("in delete"+ id);
    db.contactlist.remove({id : mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function ( err , doc){
        res.json(doc);
    });
});
```

## In summary

Add slash to `$http.delete`

```
$http.delete('/contactlist/'+ id).success( function(response) {
    refresh();
});
```

Make `id` param in your server.

```
app.delete('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) { //colons are important
    var id = req.param.id;
    console.log("in delete"+ id);
    db.contactlist.remove({id : mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function ( err , doc){
        res.json(doc);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank You. for identifying the typo

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 app.delete('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
 var id = req.params.id;
console.log("in delete"+ id);
db.contactlist.remove({id : mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function ( err , doc){
res.json(doc);
});
});
```

Your can see the doc from here to pass params with the url: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html